# Regex to match all characters before file extension

Tags: windows, regex

I'm using [this Windows application](http://www.den4b.com/?x=products&product=renamer) to batch rename a bunch of images. The application supports Regex, so I'm looking for an expression that will match everything (letters, numbers, hyphens, anything) before my file extension.

Thanks!

Comment: It's probably more efficient to use simple string functions instead of regex. something like 
    string.substr(0, string.lastIndexOf('.'))

Comment: Probably, but he's using an application that's designed to work with regular expressions.  He could probably use the PascalScript functionality to achieve this, but a regex would be easier, and this is unlikely to be the performance bottleneck in the batch process.

Comment: PascalScript is an option, too. I figured Regex would be the easier choice though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite enough information given in the question, but this is probably what you want:

```
([^/\\]+)(\.[^/\\]+?)?
```

The first capture group will contain your file's basename and the second capture group will contain the extension, including the '.' character, if it exists.

You can reference the two capture groups in the 'Replace' section with `$1` and `$2`.

Comment: Hey Bob, thanks for the expression. I basically have a bunch of images named like this: "tumblr_l5f8x9qQWX1qcqpar.jpg" and this "tumblr_l86i3h52Dv1qzi29h.jpg". What I'm trying to do is batch rename them to "image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", etc. I tried the regex you posted and got a strange error, here's a screenshot: http://i53.tinypic.com/fao7bm.png

Comment: Not sure how you're going to do the auto-incrementing number.  Hopefully ReNamer supports that, because that's not something you can easily do with a regex.

Comment: It worked. And I think ReNamer does support the auto-incrementing... let's hope so. Thanks a million Bob!